# How do I have a profile picture revert to "default" if it is externally deleted?

Tags: django

So I have created a blog with Django, where users who register have a basic default profile picture. The issue is, if I were to delete their profile picture using my hosting site (PythonAnywhere, for example), it doesn't go back to the default image, but rather just an unloaded file.

Comment: Why is your `sender` `Image`?. It should be your `model`, which in your case is `Profile`

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily have to go through all of that, it's unnecessary.

Create a method that either returns an image if it exists or the default image if it doesn't.

Here's an example

```
class Profile(models.Model):
...
...
def get_image():
   if self.image:
      return self.image.url
   # Write code to return default image
   return default_image
```

Comment: I currently have this deployed, so rather than changing much of the code I would prefer to incorporate a way to solve this issue within my current code - is there a way?